# How to read the JavaScript developer console with IE.au3

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, autoit

I have a website which sends info to the developer console of the IE with a funtion called: `console.info("spawned", t.name)` in javascript. 
I want to read whats in the console and react to it.

I have no idea. I tried it with `$oIE.console.log` but there is just no output.

/edit sorry for the short discription here is more:

I tried to get the value of a variable in the javascript with the chrome console not it always says "not defined".

```
$oIE.document.getElementByID("t").type
```

and

```
$o_object.document.parentwindow.eval($s_eval)
```

did not work either.

Here is the pastebin auf the js: http://pastebin.com/8w4zi7ns

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it would look something like this (assuming console.log is how you would reference it in javascript):

```
Global $gvData = $oIE.document.parentWindow.eval("console.log")
MsgBox(64 + 262144, "Info", $gvData)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work. I tried to get the variable directly over the chrome console but it just says "not defined"

Comment: This is intended to help you figure out how to make the javascript call and receive a value.  This is only good in Internet Explorer.  I do not know the calls you need to do in javascript to read the values.  I suggest you use something like debugbar for IE and run your javascript code in the script section to make sure the javascript your calling is even valid first.

Comment: I am trying to get it first with the console but had no success yet.
Tried dumping all vars with
`for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}`
but it did not show up.

I do not know much about javascript but I think it is because the variable is only used in a function.

The console has the object "console" and things like "console.log" but I do not know a method to get the last log. Sth. like "console.getLastLog"